# Open questions in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, validation

I was just having a short discussion with a leading researcher in statistical learning theory. He told me that in his perspective NOT the issues like speed or such matter but mostly the question how to validate models or better how to validate algorithms. I wanted to ask the community about different opinions what the currently important questions in statistical learning theory and machine learning are? (On a fundamental basis, i.e. not how to optimize certain algorithms or such).

Comment: Validation can be a problem of speed too. Certain models might be too slow to validate or sue.

Comment: Are you looking for way to validate your model or are you looking for important research questions in machine learning in general?

Comment: @Esash I am looking for problems which cannot be done efficiently on a classical computer but are important questions in daily tasks in ML and Optimisation.